# How to build a Struts custom error page with exception details and sendmail button

Tags: java, error-handling, struts

I am currently working on managing errors (404, 500) in Struts so any user that faces an error would see a convenient error page with all the details. I would also like to implement a `sendmail` feature within that error page so they could send the error message to the developers team right away.

The `sendmail` feature is already done. I just need to find a way to print the exception details on my JSP page.

Here is what I have:

**`web.xml`:**

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>500</error-code>
    <location>/jsp/common/error500.jsp</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/jsp/common/error404.jsp</location>
</error-page>
```

**JSP :**

header is :

```
<%@ page isErrorPage="true" import="java.io.*" contentType="text/plain"%>
```

tried the following:

1.

```
<div class="container" align="center">
    ERROR 404

    <html:errors/>
</div>
```

2.

```
<div class="container" align="center">
    ERROR 404

    Message:
    <%= exception.getMessage()%>

    StackTrace:
    <%
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(stringWriter);
    exception.printStackTrace(printWriter);
    out.println(stringWriter);
    printWriter.close();
    stringWriter.close();
    %>
</div>
```

As you can see the redirect works just fine. I just need to find how to print the stacktrace within the JSP.

Answer (score 1):

Normal Struts 1 exception handling uses declarative handling.

The exception is stored under `Globals.EXCEPTION_KEY` unless you provide your own key.

S1 exception handling is detailed in the [Exception Handler](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/userGuide/building_controller.html#a4.5_Exception_Handler) portion of the guide.

If you bypass the normal exception processing mechanism I'm not sure if the exception will be stored in a scope or not; you could just check to see if it's there. A 404 is a different issue than an exception, however; it's a missing mapping, not an exception.

If you're using Struts 2, it's a different, but similar process. It's very important to include the Struts version when asking questions–things changed a lot between Struts 1 and 2, and S1.2 and S1.3.

(And if you're using a version before S1.2, boo hiss.)

Comment: I have coded the Exception Handler as advised. I still can't display the stack trace on my JSP page. Any thoughts? How can I access the exception stacktrace from my error page (JSP)?

Comment: @CharleyDC5 The exception is stored under the key I listed; there are any number of options. Personally, I think displaying a stack trace o the page itself is horrible from a UX standpoint, and just isn't necessary. [This book excerpt](http://www.objectsource.com/j2eechapters/Ch18-Exception_Handling.htm) will give you a few more ideas.

Comment: I don't want to display it to the client. I want to put it in a hidden field and just show a "Send to support team" button to the client. By clicking that button, I would simply send an email to the support team using AJAX.

Comment: @CharleyDC5 Same difference, although I guess I wouldn't bother--I'd either do it automatically, or save it to a DB/stuff it in a JMS queue, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try out

```
out.println(stringWriter.getBuffer().toString());
```

Following code overrides `RequestProcessor` to put `exception` to be available in the JSP.

```
protected ActionForward processException(HttpServletRequest request,
                                       HttpServletResponse response,
                                       Exception exception,
                                       ActionForm form,
                                       ActionMapping mapping)
throws IOException, ServletException {
request.setAttribute("exception", exception);
return mapping.findForward("error");
```

}

Comment: It does not work as I have a NullPointerException on <%= exception.getMessage()%> . Looks like the exception object is not accessible from my JSP.